# Add custom label for Helm Templates

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, tilt

My helm Chart.yaml file looks like this

```
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: "0.0.1"
description: Helm chart
name: blabla
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  - name: nfs-server-provisioner
    repository: https://charts.helm.sh/stable
    version: 1.1.1
  - name: reloader
    repository: https://stakater.github.io/stakater-charts
    version: 0.0.74
```

and the tiltfile

```
k8s_resource('chart-reloader')
k8s_resource('chart-nfs-server-provisioner')
```

I'm trying to add custom label `egress: internet` to both `nfs-server-provisioner` and `reloader` but can't find a way to add.

Also, when I do `kubectl get deployments`, deployments for these pods don't show up.