# Kubernetes networkpolicy multiple match labels

Tags: kubernetes

We have a default deny-all-egress policy for all pods and we have an egress-internet policy like below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-external-egress-internet
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      egress: internet
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Now, if I try to add multiple labels under `spec/podselector/matchlabels` everything breaks. Is there a way for this network policy to get implemented on pods with label `egress: internet` OR `foo:bar`.

A pod with just `foo:bar` as label should be allowed but it's not working that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats tricky because `matchLabels` does not take multiple key&value pairs and `matchExpressions` will be ANDed.
There are two possible ways (workarounds):

1. Create another networkpolicy (along with the existing one) where `matchLabels` contains `foo:bar`.

   [or]
2. add a new label(common) to both the workloads and use that in `podSelector`

Comment: I figured creating seperate network policy was the way to go..
Adding a new label to `nfs-server-provisioner` deployment was not possible because it's coming from helm. I actually spent couple of days debugging and asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630442/add-custom-label-for-helm-templates) but no response.

Comment: podSelector.matchLabels does take multiple key-values.  See my answer below

Answer (score 7):

You can add multiple key-values to podSelector.matchLabels.
See https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/10-allowing-traffic-with-multiple-selectors.md

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: redis-allow-services
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bookstore
      role: db
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: bookstore
          role: search
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: bookstore
          role: api
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: inventory
          role: web
```

Comment: Ah, that's great to know!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can stack the podSelector like

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      egress: internet
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: newPod
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```